# Monthly payment input calculator

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to java, and I'm trying to write a program that will give me the monthly payments, interest total and total amount paid on a bank loan, but I believe either my math is wrong or is incorrectly formatted, because when I run it I get numbers in the negatives, and payments that I know are wrong. Could you point out where I have made the mistake?

Example :

```
7500 (amount borrowed) 
14.5 (loan rate)
3 (# of years)
```

The expected output would be

```
258.16 (monthly payment)
1793.66 (interest paid)
9293.66 (total paid).
```

Code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog58i
{
public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner numberReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("The amount I wish to borrow is? ");
    int p = numberReader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("The loan rate I can get is? ");
    double r = numberReader.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("How mny years will it take me to pay off the loan? ");
    int m = (numberReader.nextInt())*12; 

    double MP = (1 +(r/1200)); 
    MP = Math.pow(MP, m);
    double payment = p *(r/1200) * (MP/(MP-1));
    payment = (int)(m * 100+0.5)/100.0;
    double total = (int)((m * payment)*100)/100.0;
    double intetotal = (int)((total - p)*100)/100.0;

    System.out.println("My monthly payments will be " + payment);
    System.out.println("Total Interest Paid is " + intetotal);
    System.out.println("Total amount paid is " + total);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the current output and specify the desired output?

Comment: Give us some examples of your input, and expected but actual outputs.

Comment: This looks rather suspect: `double MP = (1 +(r/1200)); ` Why 1200?

Comment: The equation to calculate monthly payments is  Monthly payments= p*(r/1200)*((1+((r/1200)^m)/(1+(r/1200)^m))

Comment: @popovitsj it is the first step to calculate the monthly interest amount = rate is a percentage so it has to be divided by 100 and to know the monthly interests rate, divide your yearly IR by 12

Comment: @WillP. Didn't my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your formula, this statement seems to be wrong

```
double MP = (1 + (r / 1200));

MP = Math.pow(MP, m);
```

The power is only on `(r / 1200)` not on `(1 + (r / 1200))`